# mongoose When I Use update it updates Nothing with status 200(success)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I use update Query for push some data in array in Mongodb and I use mongoose in nodeJs.Pplease anyone can help out from this.

#### Model Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, require: true },
    username: { type: String, require: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    creation_dt: { type: String, require: true },
    tasks : []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',schema)
```

So I use this schema and I want to push data in tasks array and here is my route code for pushing data.

#### Route For Update Data in Tasks:

```
router.post("/newTask", isValidUser, (req, res) => {
  addToDataBase(req, res);
});

async function addToDataBase(req, res) {
  var dataa = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime,
  };
  var usr = new User(req.user);
  usr.update({ email: req.user.email }, { $push: { tasks: dataa } });
  console.log(req.user.email);
  try {
    doc = await usr.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }
}
```

Here I create a async function and call that function in route but when I post data using postman it response with status code 200(success) but it updates nothing in my database.

#### Output screenshot:

[image: Output]
as you can see in this image task : [].. it updates nothing in that array but status is success 
I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: The status has nothing to do with the state of the DB. It can be 200 when the server's process executed successfully. There can be no DB transaction at all and it can be 200. You need to unit test your back-end instead of do postman end-to-end testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this task easier using findOneAndUpdate method.

```js
router.put("/users", isValidUser, async (req, res) => {
  var data = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime,
  };

  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: req.user.email },
      {
        $push: {
          tasks: data,
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send("User with email not found");
    }
    res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Also I strongly suggest using raw / JSON data for request body, that's how most ui libraries (reactjs, angular) send data.

[image]

To be able to parse json data, you need to add the following line to your main file before using routes.

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

**TEST**

Existing user:

```
{
    "tasks": [],
    "_id": "5e8b349dc285884b64b6b167",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "username": "Kirtan",
    "password": "123213",
    "creation_dt": "2020-04-06T14:21:40",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "pName": "pName 1",
    "pTitle": "pTitle 1",
    "pStartTime": "pStartTime 1",
    "pEndTime": "pEndTime 1",
    "pSessionTime": "pSessionTime 1"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "pName": "pName 1",
            "pTitle": "pTitle 1",
            "pStartTime": "pStartTime 1",
            "pEndTime": "pEndTime 1",
            "pSessionTime": "pSessionTime 1"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5e8b349dc285884b64b6b167",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "username": "Kirtan",
    "password": "123213",
    "creation_dt": "2020-04-06T14:21:40",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Also as a side note, you had better to create unique indexes on username and email fields. This can be done applying `unique: true` option in the schema, but better to create these unique indexes at mongodb shell like this:

```js
db.users.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } );
db.users.createIndex( { "username": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Comment: I use your Code in my Project and check using postman but the problem is when i throw a put req first time it sends data but after that when i fire put request for the 2nd 3rd and 4th time postman response like [link](https://ibb.co/kxk789C) [link](https://ibb.co/tXZcPxB) please find the url of image i attached the output and code so you get some idea

Comment: @Kirtan can you apply isValidUser middlere, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Kirtan I also added this line `app.use(express.json());` to the question. By the way do you try to post multiple tasks? Can you show the request body in postman?

Comment: Thank You so Much For solving this problem i'm trying to solve this from last 3 day and night i check stackoverflow youtube google but i got error in every different solution but finally you solved this Thank you again for save my time... IT WORKS

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've done mongoose, but I'm pretty sure `<model>.update()` also actively updates the record in Mongo.

You use `.update()` when you want to update an existing record in Mongo, but you are instantiating a new `User` model (i.e. creating a new user)

try the following code instead for a NEW USER:

```js
router.post('/newTask', isValidUser, (req, res) => {

  addToDataBase(req,res)

})
async function addToDataBase(req, res) {

  var dataa = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime
  }

  // email field is already in `req.user` 
  var usr = new User({ ...req.user, tasks: [dataa] });

  console.log(req.user.email);
  try {
    await usr.save();
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }

}
```

Now, if you wanted to update an existing record :

```js
router.post('/newTask', isValidUser, (req, res) => {

  addToDataBase(req,res)

})
async function addToDataBase(req, res) {

  var dataa = {
    pName: req.body.pName,
    pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
    pStartTime: req.body.pStartTime,
    pEndTime: req.body.pEndTime,
    pSessionTime: req.body.pSessionTime
  }


  try {
    await usr. updateOne({ email : req.user.email}, { $push: { tasks: dataa } });
    return res.status(201).json(doc);
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(501).json(err);
  }

}
```

For more info read: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

Comment: Your First Code(try the following code instead for a NEW USER) works fine with new User but the second code(Now, if you wanted to update an existing record ) Gives the output in postman : {} nothing insert in database or nothing update in output

Comment: And in second example of code you forgot to write   var usr = new User(req.user)  but i add that by my side Then after output is {} .... have any idea to what i do next ?

Comment: yeah, it's been a while since I used mongoose, perhaps try to add `$set` ? :     await usr.update({ email : req.user.email}, {$set:  { $push: { tasks: dataa } } });

Comment: also, I'm just realizing that `updateOne` might be more appropriate, I will update the code above

Comment: Hey i use your new code and i got output the same as before [link](https://ibb.co/5FtDrHf) [link] (https://ibb.co/cYPWchG) here is the link of code and output